# Mongo RealmSync Getting Error: Encountered non-recoverable resume token error

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-realm

I am getting the below error Mongo RealmSync, after that i need to manually re-enable the sync process.

Anyone know, what is the cause of that error,
encountered non-recoverable resume token error. Sync cannot be resumed from this state and must be terminated and re-enabled to continue functioning: (ChangeStreamHistoryLost) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Resume of change stream was not possible, as the resume point may no longer be in the oplog.

Note: My sync don't have many transactions which is syncing.

Comment: When you receive server related errors (check the Realm console!), your best bet is to reach out to Realm directly. That have a live Chat on their website when you log into console and there's also Forums as well (start with Chat). There's nothing anyone here on SO can do about those errors. If it's NOT a server error then we need to see the code that produces those errors and what we can do to duplicate it. I am also seeing those errors in console FYI.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because server related errors cannot be corrected by anyone here on SO. Please reach out to the hosting service for support.